# Rename the extension of many files

Tags: extension, rename

I would like to rename the extension `.tar?h=ocdist105&=%2Fdata1%2F4070d0f0f1d62757%2Frequested_files` for just `.tar`
I tried the command

```
rename 's/\.tar?h=ocdist105&p=%2Fdata1%2F4070d0f0f1d62757%2Frequested_files$/.tar/' *.tar?h=ocdist105&p=%2Fdata1%2F4070d0f0f1d62757%2Frequested_files
```

but it seems not to be working. I have 550 files with that extension. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cd` to your folder and run `mmv '*.tar*' '#1.tar'`

If you don't have mmv installed run `sudo apt-get install mmv`

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to accomplish this using find, exec, and rename.  I'm fairly sure this will run on Ubuntu without needing anything special.

```
#!/bin/bash

find /path/to/files -name "*.tar?h=ocdist105&=%2Fdata1%2F4070d0f0f1d62757%2Frequested_files" -exec rename .tar?h=ocdist105&=%2Fdata1%2F4070d0f0f1d62757%2Frequested_files .tar {} \;
```

This has not been tested, but should work.  Here is what the command looks like when trying to rename the extension `.css` to `.txt` for example; for clarity.

```
#!/bin/bash

find /path/to/files -name "*.css" -exec rename .css .txt {} \;
```

**To Use**

Put the above content in a file.  Give the file executable permissions, and run it.

**TESTING**

You can test the above command to see what the result will be without actually making changes by adding `-n` after the `rename`.

```
#!/bin/bash

find /path/to/files -name "*.css" -exec rename -n .css .txt {} \;
```

Comment: I gave the permissions and runned it, but it replied that there is a missing argument  for '-exec'. Sorry, but I am not used with ubuntu

Comment: @user253334 make sure you edit the code where it says `/path/to/files` with your folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Both `rename` and your shell treat some character as special. You should properly escape them.

This command should do the work:

```
rename 's/\.tar\?h\=ocdist105\&\=%2Fdata1%2F4070d0f0f1d62757%2Frequested_files$/.tar/' *.tar\?h\=ocdist105\&\=%2Fdata1%2F4070d0f0f1d62757%2Frequested_files
```

If you want to know how I generated that command, just know that tab-completion is a helpful friend when dealing with this sort of problems.